# Where can I get a device with 'Ubuntu for phones' pre-installed?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Canonical has recently announced [Ubuntu for phones](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone), which is Ubuntu with a specific interface for mobile devices.

Where can I get phones with this version of Ubuntu pre-installed? If no devices are available yet, where can I pre-order one?

Comment: Shopping advice or "where can I buy" question are not within the [topicness of Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: @Braiam This isn't a shopping recommendation question; they know exactly *what* they want to buy. Moreover, it can be answered objectively without reaming through dozens of questions (which is what that post complains about).

Comment: @Oli "Where **can I get phones** with this version of Ubuntu pre-installed?" if it isn't you tell me what is? In the entire SE, nobody tells you where to buy stuff.

Comment: See also: [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support](http://askubuntu.com/q/236276/178596)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the 9th February 2015, Canonical's partner, BQ has announced that Ubuntu Touch will be [pre-installed](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/02/06/bqs-new-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition-the-smartphone-that-puts-content-and-services-at-your-fingertips/) and can be purchased on-line.  This phone is intended for the European market only.

---

> Meizu has finally confirmed that it plans to use an MX4 device to present the Ubuntu system at [Mobile World Congress 2015](http://www.mobileworldcongress.com/about/start-here/2015-preview/) in Barcelona (March 2 and 5). This phone is intended for the European and Chinese market only with April as an expected release month.
>
> **Specs**
>
> Quad-core 2.2 GHz Cortex A17 processor and a quad-core 1.7 GHz A7 processor, and the two are used in tandem or separately, depending on needs.
>
> It also comes with a 5.36-inch Sharp/JDI display, at a 1920 x 1152 resolution, and Corning Gorilla Glass 3, and a 20.7-megapixel back camera (2MP on the front one).

[More on Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Meizu-to-Officially-Launch-MX4-with-Ubuntu-at-MWC-2015-Will-Sell-It-Internationally-474335.shtml)

---

**According to OMG! Ubuntu!**

> America will hear news about an exclusive Ubuntu Phone from an as-yet-unnamed manufacturer in June.

Comment: Made answer CW to encourage others to add to this as and when new phones become available.

Comment: May need updating for the [Aquaris E5](http://store.bq.com/en/ubuntu-edition-e5)

Answer (score 2):

The BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition is now availble in the [BQ web shop](http://www.bq.com/es/ubuntu.html) for the EU-European market, but still the only model with Ubuntu pre-installed.

EDIT: Some days ago the [BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition](http://store.bq.com/es/ubuntu-edition-e5) has been released.

Answer (score 1):

> After a long wait, Ubuntu phones became a reality this year. But now
>   Linux fans outside of Europe and China will be able to try out the
>   newcomer OS for the very first time. Spanish smartphone maker BQ has
>   announced that it is now shipping its Aquarius E5 Ubuntu smartphone
>   across the world.

2015.08.08

source: http://www.theverge.com/2015/8/8/9121611/aquarius-b5-ubuntu-edition-available-worldwide