# Are there plans to provide Ubuntu on more (bq) smartphonses?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

The BQ `Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition` is the only official Ubuntu smartphone currently. Are there plans to enlarge the product palette to include other BQ devices (I'm especially interested in the `Aquaris E6`) or other smartphones in general.

I know that the first attempt to collection funding for an Ubuntu smartphone failed dramatically, but now that the flashsales of the `E4.5` were a success, there might be some news I missed. Following BQ on Twitter in a non-English language is kind of annoying...

Comment: Impossible for us to answer since we are not BQ. Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/235665/where-can-i-get-a-device-with-ubuntu-for-phones-pre-installed That will get updated with new information when available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, from some tweets by BQ itself, they have no plans to release another device with Ubuntu. I still do not know if they will continue selling the Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition after these flash sales. I do not know if the flash sales where a success because there is a kind of silence regarding how many where sold. I tried to get one and it was quiet difficult the first flash sales.

You already will know that Meizu is due to release its MX4 with Ubuntu (in Asia and Europe) and there should be another company involved for America (but still there is no information about who and when).