# Ubuntu Phones usable in Belgium?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'd like very much to try one of the official Ubuntu phones for my regular telephone usage. The problem is that I am total newbie what concerns mobiles.

Can somebody advise me on a model usable in Belgium ?

Again, my apologies for asking what is probably a no-brainer. :-)

UPDATE:

It was a dumb question indeed. Simply match the phone's supported frequencies with those used in Belgium. Checking the countries' frequencies at http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html. It seems Europe is mainly using 900Mhz and 1800Mhz. So if the phone can use those too, then it should be usable in whole Europe.

Comment: I see no reason why any model can not be usable in Belgium.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get a device with 'Ubuntu for phones' pre-installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235665/where-can-i-get-a-device-with-ubuntu-for-phones-pre-installed)

Comment: @pilot6 because I don't know squat about it. And that Belgium is usually not in the lead of adopting new technology. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one in Belgium.  It runs out of the box and I bought it from bq.com.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Right - I now know how to match the frequencies of the phone with those of the country. :-) So basically all three Ubuntu phone should work in Belgium indeed. Which model did you buy ? And are you satisfied ?

Comment: I have Aquaris E5.  No problem so far, except disconnection when i use it in my car with bluetooth (a bug is already file for this).